# How to seal plaster before using the Anti Mould Paint

Tags: paint, plaster, wallpaper, sealer

I had some mould (due to condensation) on bedroom wallpaper so I have removed all the wallpapers. I am planning to paint the wall with Ronseal Anti-Mould Paint instead of using wallpapers. Also, bought a dehumidifier to fix the condensation issue.

Ronseal website suggests I need to seal the plaster before using the Anti Mould Paint for a newly prepared plaster. In my case, there were wallpapers on the wall so I think it still applies to me.

Can you please suggest how to seal plaster? If you can suggest any available products then it would be very useful.

Below is the photo of my wall after I removed all wallpapers.

EDIT: I talked to Ronseal, they suggested I need first coat of anti-condensation paint and followed by anti-mould paint. They think I do not need to seal the wall. I think I am more confused now :S

[image]

[image]

Comment: The wall looks to have been painted before wall paper so rules about sealing new plaster would have been followed before that paint was applied    Now the most important thing is to remove all traces of wallpaper adhesive either by sanding or washing.   Then follow the advice given regarding condensation blocking etc..,

Comment: Thanks @Kris - the wall has anti damp coating on the corners (yellow color) but the rest of the wall is brown which leads me to think it may not have been sealed. Is there anyway I can check this?

Comment: Scratch into the surface a bit to see if you find a different color material below the brown.

Comment: I just did, i can feel a bit of white color. However, the brown wall doesnt seem to be painted (looking at the surface). I have also attached its picture for your reference.

Comment: If I were to seal I would use a bins or kilzs shellac paint. I don’t like the idea of sealing mold if it is moist you trap it and it keeps growing. I will spray the area down with 3% hydrogen peroxide let dry then coat with whatever.  Is your anti mold paint rated for indoor use? Many are not. I live in the Pacific Northwest where mold is a way of life and although I have used some paints that have inhibitors most state not for indoor use, but it has been a few years since I needed this type of product. Helping the humidity low may be a better solution if the paint is not for indoor use.